# jQuery simplemodal "TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and the latest version of simple-modal jQuery plugin.

I'm trying to figure what the init function of jQuery is. Maybe I'm thinking this is a conflict with another library.

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#freeshipping').click(function(){
        $('#freeshippingmodal').modal({
        });
    });
    $('#easyreturns').click(function(){
        $('#easyreturnsmodal').modal();
    });
    $('#5tocharity').click(function(){
        $('#5tocharitymodal').modal();
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="CallToAction">
    <div id="freeshipping" class="call">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id='freeshippingmodal' class='simplemodal-container'>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="CallToAction">
    <div id="easyreturns" class="call">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="easyreturnsmodal" class="simplemodal-container">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="CallToAction">
    <div id="5tocharity" class="call">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="5tocharitymodal" class="simplemodal-container">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="simplemodal-overlay">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide link to Plugin? Even great if you could create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: How did you add your jquery & jquery simple modal plugin ? Code Please!

Comment: THis is the plugin: http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal-1-4-4-released/

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/content/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js"></script>

Comment: why you don't use jquery ui if you want to open modal?

Comment: I don't know. I have always used this one.

Comment: i added answer. see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

and then

```
$('#freeshipping').click(function(){
    $('#freeshippingmodal').dialog({
        modal: true
    });
});
```

to open modal